# My android application (mapView) is not properly showing if it is not inside MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-development, mapbox-android

I am creating a navigation app using Mapbox's SDKs and APIs. I am trying to put my customized Map with user location app inside a class (PagePlanRoute.kt) inside my project but it is only showing properly when the code is inside the MainActivity class. Whenever I put my codes on my class (PagePlanRoute.kt), the Map is not working properly. It only shows a default Map without the user location. I am stuck with this. Please help. Used language here is Kotlin.

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.prototype">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Prototype"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".PageRouteReviews"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".PageRideDetails"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
<activity
android:name=".PageOnRide"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PageExplore"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PagePlanRoute"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PageOverview"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

page_plan_route.xml:

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#C8C8C8"
tools:context=".PagePlanRoute">



<com.mapbox.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="15.588809484318716"
    app:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="120.97635174743579"
    app:mapbox_cameraZoom="12.5"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="118dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="345dp" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#7209B7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backPlanRoute"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="198dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/backPlanRoute"
        android:text="Plan my route"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</RelativeLayout>


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="#E41B1B"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mapView">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/inputRoute"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/directionIcon"
            android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text"
            android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Find route"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/directionIcon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:background="#00BA5757"
            android:tag="gray"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/directions_ic" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/inputLocationCard"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#00803333"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="56dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView01"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_outline_circle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView02"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_my_location_24" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView02"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-55dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dot" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dot" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dot" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/yourLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Your Location"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingStart="5dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/targetLocation"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Destination"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingStart="5dp" />



    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/inputPreferenceCard"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Gradient:"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/findRouteBtn"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#7209B7"
            android:text="Find Route"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="100"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.909"
            app:trackColor="#575757" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gradientLevel"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/seekBar"
            android:text="0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/seekBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/seekBar" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

PagePlanRoute.kt

class PagePlanRoute : AppCompatActivity() {

```
//mapbox map--------------------------------------------------------

private lateinit var locationPermissionHelper: LocationPermissionHelper

private val onIndicatorBearingChangedListener = OnIndicatorBearingChangedListener {
    mapView.getMapboxMap().setCamera(CameraOptions.Builder().bearing(it).build())
}

private val onIndicatorPositionChangedListener = OnIndicatorPositionChangedListener {
    mapView.getMapboxMap().setCamera(CameraOptions.Builder().center(it).build())
    mapView.gestures.focalPoint = mapView.getMapboxMap().pixelForCoordinate(it)
}

private val onMoveListener = object : OnMoveListener {
    override fun onMoveBegin(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {
        onCameraTrackingDismissed()
    }

    override fun onMove(detector: MoveGestureDetector): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onMoveEnd(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {}
}
private lateinit var mapView: MapView

//mapbox map---------------------------------------------

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mapView = MapView(this)
    setContentView(R.layout.page_plan_route)
    locationPermissionHelper = LocationPermissionHelper(WeakReference(this))
    locationPermissionHelper.checkPermissions {
        onMapReady()
    }


    currLocation = findViewById(R.id.yourLocation)
    targetLocation = findViewById(R.id.targetLocation)
    back = findViewById(R.id.backPlanRoute)
    // exitPopUp = findViewById(R.id.planPopUpBack)
    searchText = findViewById(R.id.inputRoute)
    directionButton = findViewById(R.id.directionIcon)
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar)
    levelText = findViewById(R.id.gradientLevel)
    findRoute = findViewById(R.id.findRouteBtn)
    dialog = Dialog(this)
    savePopDialog = Dialog(this)
    loadingDialog = Dialog(this)

    // sample user
    userId = 2

    // accept the passed value
    val intent = intent
    val userChoice = intent.getStringExtra("key")
    if (userChoice == "1") {  // plan route
        // show input fields
        directionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_direction_violet)
        showInputFields("violet")
    } else if (userChoice == "0") { // start journey
        // hide input fields
        hideInputFields("gray")
    }
    // on welcome page when
    //      PlanRoute is click - display input fields (direction icon - color violet)
    //      Start journey is click - hide input field (direction icon - color gray)

    // back button
    back.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        finish()
        val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "route click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        toast.show()
    })

    // search bar input text ----- have auto complete -- map will move according to the inputed route (i guess)


    // toggle button
    directionButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        //                make it toggle button
        println("This is image tag: " + directionButton.getTag())
        if (directionButton.getTag() === "gray") {
            // change color of icon and tag
            directionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_direction_violet)
            showInputFields("violet")
        } else if (directionButton.getTag() === "violet") {
            // change color of icon and tag
            directionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.directions_ic)
            hideInputFields("gray")
        }
    })

    // slide bar
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progresValue: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {}
        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}
        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
            levelText.setText(seekBar.progress.toString())
        }
    })

    // input fields clear error
    currLocation.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
            if (currLocation.getText().length != 0) {
                currLocation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_edit_text)
            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {}
    })
    targetLocation.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
            if (targetLocation.getText().length != 0) {
                targetLocation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_edit_text)
            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {}
    })

    // find route click
    findRoute.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        var isValidInput = true


        // get seek bar level
        val barLevel = seekBar.getProgress()

        // check input text
        if (currLocation.getText().isEmpty()) {
            currLocation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_error)
            isValidInput = false
        }
        if (targetLocation.getText().isEmpty()) {
            targetLocation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_error)
            isValidInput = false
        }
        if (targetLocation.getText().isNotEmpty()) {
            isValidInput = true
        }
        if (currLocation.getText().isNotEmpty()) {
            isValidInput = true
        }
        if (isValidInput) {
            // radio button not working
            startLoc = currLocation.text.toString()
            destination = targetLocation.text.toString()
            println("Current Location: " + currLocation.text)
            println("Target Location: " + targetLocation.text)
            println("Level: $barLevel")

            // run code to pop up the results
            // showSuggestedRoutes(currLocation.getText(), targetLocation.getText(), String.valueOf(barLevel), String.valueOf(radioButton)){}
            // private void showSuggestedRoutes(String curr, String target, String elevation, String bikeLane){}
            // make model for routesSuggestionCard
            showSuggestedRoutes()
        }
    })
}

private fun onMapReady() {
    mapView.getMapboxMap().setCamera(
        CameraOptions.Builder()
            .zoom(14.0)
            .build()
    )
    mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri("mapbox://styles/jericho00010/cl6y8iwmw003u15qfkli5qptl")

    // Style.MAPBOX_STREETS
    {
        initLocationComponent()
        setupGesturesListener()
    }
}

private fun setupGesturesListener() {
    mapView.gestures.addOnMoveListener(onMoveListener)
}

private fun initLocationComponent() {

    val locationComponentPlugin = mapView.location
    locationComponentPlugin.updateSettings {
        this.enabled = true
        this.pulsingEnabled = true
        this.locationPuck = LocationPuck2D(
            bearingImage = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
                this@PagePlanRoute,
                com.mapbox.maps.R.drawable.mapbox_user_puck_icon
            ),
            shadowImage = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
                this@PagePlanRoute,
                com.mapbox.maps.R.drawable.mapbox_user_icon_shadow,
            ),
            scaleExpression = interpolate {
                linear()
                zoom()
                stop {
                    literal(0.0)
                    literal(0.6)
                }
                stop {
                    literal(20.0)
                    literal(1.0)
                }
            }.toJson()
        )
    }
    locationComponentPlugin.addOnIndicatorPositionChangedListener(onIndicatorPositionChangedListener)
    locationComponentPlugin.addOnIndicatorBearingChangedListener(onIndicatorBearingChangedListener)
}

private fun onCameraTrackingDismissed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onCameraTrackingDismissed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    mapView.location
        .removeOnIndicatorPositionChangedListener(onIndicatorPositionChangedListener)
    mapView.location
        .removeOnIndicatorBearingChangedListener(onIndicatorBearingChangedListener)
    mapView.gestures.removeOnMoveListener(onMoveListener)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mapView.location
        .removeOnIndicatorBearingChangedListener(onIndicatorBearingChangedListener)
    mapView.location
        .removeOnIndicatorPositionChangedListener(onIndicatorPositionChangedListener)
    mapView.gestures.removeOnMoveListener(onMoveListener)
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    locationPermissionHelper.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}




private fun hideInputFields(color: String) {
    directionButton.tag = color
    val inputLocationCard = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.inputLocationCard)
    val inputPreferenceCard = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.inputPreferenceCard)
    inputLocationCard.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    inputPreferenceCard.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}

private fun showInputFields(color: String) {
    directionButton.tag = color
    val inputLocationCard = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.inputLocationCard)
    val inputPreferenceCard = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.inputPreferenceCard)
    inputLocationCard.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    inputPreferenceCard.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

private fun sendData() {
    val intent = Intent(this@PagePlanRoute, PageOnRide::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("userId", userId.toString())
    intent.putExtra("routeId", routeId.toString())
    intent.putExtra("startLoc", startLoc)
    intent.putExtra("destination", destination)
    println("-----------Send On Data-----------")
    println("user: $userId")
    println("route: $routeId")
    println("start: $startLoc")
    println("destination: $destination")
    println("----------------------------------")
    startActivity(intent)
}

private fun showSuggestedRoutes() {
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop_route_suggest)
    dialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    val goBtn = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.suggestRouteGoBtn)
    val exitPlanPopUp = dialog.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.planPopUpBack)
    val saveRouteBtn = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.suggestRouteSaveBtn)
    val seeMore = dialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.viewMoreText)
    routeIdText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.testRouteId)
    dialog.show()

    // pick one of the suggested route to start
    goBtn.setOnClickListener { // get user's current location
        // get user's destination
        // get id of selected route
        // pass this to PageOnRide page
        routeId = routeIdText.getText().toString().toInt()
        sendData()
    }

    // exit pop up
    exitPlanPopUp.setOnClickListener { dialog.dismiss() }
    saveRouteBtn.setOnClickListener { showLoadingDialog() }
    seeMore.setOnClickListener { // pass route name or Id
        startActivity(Intent(this@PagePlanRoute, PageRouteReviews::class.java))
    }
}

private fun showSaveSuccess() {
    savePopDialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop_route_save)
    savePopDialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    val handler = Handler()
    val runnable = Runnable {
        println("-----------Save Route Data-----------")
        println("user: $userId")
        println("route: $routeId")
        println("start: $startLoc")
        println("destination: $destination")
        println("----------------------------------")
        savePopDialog.dismiss()
    }
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000)
    savePopDialog.show()
}

private fun showLoadingDialog() {
    loadingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop_loading)
    loadingDialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    loadingDialog.show()
    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed({
        loadingDialog.dismiss()
        showSaveSuccess()
    }, 5000)
}
```

Comment: Mind sharing some code?

Comment: Hi @IvanGarza, I already did sir. Hope you can help me out. Thanks!